# RubyMine не видит и не устанавливает Rails (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Руби и рейлз устанавливал через терминал, руби подхватился. Сама РубиМайн не хочет ставить ни гемсы, ни сдк. Сыплются ошибки.

Типа таких:

```html
Following gems were not installed:
rails (4.2.1):  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
     Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /home/mrkrot617/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.6/tests/test_json.rb
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил и выбрал RVM, RubyMine просит установить недостающие гемсы через bundle. Жму инсталл и получаю ошибку (сразу ругалась на права доступа к папке):

```html
bash -c "/home/mrkrot617/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.6.0 do /home/mrkrot617/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby /home/mrkrot617/projects/hello_app/bin/bundle install"
There was an error accessing `/home/mrkrot617/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions`.
The underlying system error is Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /home/mrkrot617/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions
```

Comment: А как ты ставил руби в самом при самом начале?

Comment: по инструкции с оф сайта

Comment: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#apt ? `sudo apt-get install ruby-full`?

Comment: Да, так и устанавливал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была с установленными рельсами. Надо было удалить руби, рейлз, RVM. Далее аккуратно по 2 инструкциям установить RVM. И всё заработало.

https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm - тут ставим RVM

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rvm-on-ubuntu-16-04 - тут рейлз с пункта Installing Specific Ruby and Rails Versions.

Также советую внимательно читать что там написано))